# Improve Performance -Update query with OR in WHERE

Tags: sql-server, performance

How do we improve this Update query Performance as currently it is taking 1 Minute to update 17643 Rows.

Query ->

```
  Declare @date datetime = '09-Dec-2013' 
    update  #tmp_sp_abc  
    set     test = rtrim(xyz_test)  
    from    #tmp_sp_abc t1,  
            t_h_bg_pc_it t2  
    where   (t2.id_i = t1.i or t2.id_s1 = t1.s)  
    and     t1.r_type = 1  
    and     t2.[date] = @date
```

Tables Row Count: - 
    #tmp_sp_abc -> 125352
        t_h_bg_pc_it -> 14798 Rows

`t_h_bg_pc_it` table has 300 columns with primary key on id_i column
and `#tmp_sp_abc` has 11 columns with no primary key and no indexes.

found that "OR" condition is the root cause of this much time consumption but, can't change it.

tried to add indexes on: -

```
Table: - t_h_bg_pc_it 
Columns: - [xyz_test], [id_i], [id_s1], [date]

Table: - #tmp_sp_abc 
Columns: - [i], [s], [r_type] include [test]
```

but, by doing this saved only 5 seconds.

Attaching the Execution Plan Snaps (Without above indexes and with indexes).

[image: UpdateQueryExecutionPlans]

Please advice.

Comment: Of course you can change it. Instead of one query with `OR`, make two queries without `OR`. It's a common practice

Comment: Please Define "can't change it." Is it a 3rd party application? Because the reason why it's slow is because of the nested loop join operator. In this case, it's there because of your OR in the JOIN. One solution would be as foibs suggests, seperate the delete in 2 statements. Another one would be to rewrite the OR join into 2 AND joins and JOINING those together. Let us know if you can change anything to the code. I'd be happy to give an example.

Comment: the Nested loop join causes SQL Server to pull 125352 records 14798 times out of the temp table.

Comment: Please confirm what aspects you can change and what you can't and why. The indexes you have added don't seem particularly helpful anyway. You could try `t_h_bg_pc_it([date], [xyz_test], [id_i], [id_s1])` and `#tmp_sp_abc( [r_type], [s]) include ([i], [test])` or `#tmp_sp_abc( [r_type], [i]) include ([s], [test])
`

Answer (score 1):

The best option if you really want to squeeze out the most is to parallelise the query.

Instead of a single UPDATE, run multiple copies. Each of them operate on a subset of the data in the temporary table. Keep adding more copies and more subsets until you run out of cores of CPU (whatever happens first).

If you don't have the ability to parallelise. Run two UPDATES, one that works on the first part of the OR, another on the second. If possible, add indexes on `t_h_bg_pc_it` to support both queries. Like this:

```
Declare @date datetime = '09-Dec-2013' 
update  #tmp_sp_abc  
set     test = rtrim(xyz_test)  
from    #tmp_sp_abc t1
join    t_h_bg_pc_it t2 
  on    t2.id_i = t1.i
where   t1.r_type = 1  
and     t2.[date] = @date

update  #tmp_sp_abc  
set     test = rtrim(xyz_test)  
from    #tmp_sp_abc t1
join    t_h_bg_pc_it t2 
  on    tt2.id_s1 = t1.s
where   t1.r_type = 1  
and     t2.[date] = @date
```

You can now index `t_h_bg_pc_it` on both `s, date, xyz_test` and `id_id, date, xyz_test` (two indexes). This should speed things up. It may also be useful to index `#tmp_sp_abc` on `r_type`. If possible, do both the parallelism and the indexing/rewrite.

Finally: Fire whoever it is that comes up with naming conventions for your tables. Life is too short for this type of cryptic naming, SQL Server does auto-completion.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer because it actually is another approach. Have you just tried removing the or in the JOIN?

```
where   (t2.id_i = t1.i or t2.id_s1 = t1.s)  
and     t1.r_type = 1  
and     t2.[date] = @date
```

You can:

Reformulate it without aan OR in the top line

```
WHERE
(t2.id_i = t1.i and t1.r_type = 1  and t2.[date] = @date)
OR
(t2.id_s1 = t1.s and t1.r_type = 1  and t2.[date] = @date)
```

and give that a try.

Alternatively you could try a double join - t2, t3 instead of t2 - and split the conditions there and see what happens.

Both have a chance to allow the query optimizer to work out different paths.

Theoreitcally they should be identically, but I am not sure how much they optimize joins for 2 ORed conditions.

That said, also try to formulate that in the more moden ANSI syntax (JOIN ON).